# How do you upload a image file and a json with curl?

Tags: command-line, curl

I'm trying to use command line curl to test an API.  The call takes in some parameters and a image file.  Is there a way for me to specify the parameters using a json file, and make the request via curl so both the image file and the json file gets uploaded to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the curl documentation [here](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/curl/index.html)

In the POST (HTTP) part you'll find the answer to your question.

You need to use the -F parameter

Comment: I really hoped there was a way to put your params in a file, that way I don't have to type them every time.  Found a quick hack where I just created a ruby script calling system("your command").  Not the best solution but it saves me some typing

Comment: This link is broken, there should be some more explanation, at least an example use so that it can help other.

Comment: Agree with @mushfiq. Appreciate you answering but needs more explanation.